# adding Image to tab

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qimage

i have encountered another problem maybe you all could help with i cant seem to add a photo to any of my tabs could you help?

here is my code

```
import sys
import webbrowser
import random
import time
import os
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QIcon, QLabel, QPixmap


class UICreator(QWidget):  # |||| CREATOR TAB |||
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UICreator, self).__init__(parent)

        self.Back = QPushButton("<- Back", self)
        self.Back.resize(50, 25)
        self.Back.move(0, 425)
        self.Creator = QPushButton("YouTube", self)
        self.Creator.resize(100, 40)
        self.Creator.move(25, 50)
        self.CreatorB2 = QPushButton("Twitter", self)
        self.CreatorB2.resize(100, 40)
        self.CreatorB2.move(275, 50)
        self.CreatorL = QLabel("Created By: PapaKliffy", self)
        self.CreatorL.move(20, 350)
```

## MainWindow here

```
def startUICreatorTab(self):

    self.Creator = UICreator(self)
    self.setWindowTitle("Kliffy's SS Tool V2.0 | Creator Tab")
    self.setCentralWidget(self.Creator)
    self.Creator.Back.clicked.connect(self.startUIWindow)
    self.Creator.Creator.clicked.connect(self.Kliffy)
    self.Creator.CreatorB2.clicked.connect(self.Kliffy2)
    self.show()
```

Comment: You want to put pictures to the buttons? Because I do not see any tab.

Comment: explain more please

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dna24j

Comment: this is what i have i just want to add a picture to the back of it not sure on how to do so

Comment: Do you want to add a background image?

Comment: Yea thats all i want to do is add a backgound image to it and i cant figur out how as im really new to PyQt4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be override `paintEvent`

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPainter, QPixmap, QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel


class UICreator(QWidget):  # |||| CREATOR TAB |||
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UICreator, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(QSize(450, 450))
        self.Back = QPushButton("<- Back", self)
        self.Back.resize(50, 25)
        self.Back.move(0, 425)
        self.Creator = QPushButton("Youtube", self)
        self.Creator.resize(100, 40)
        self.Creator.move(50, 50)
        self.CreatorB2 = QPushButton("Twitter", self)
        self.CreatorB2.resize(100, 40)
        self.CreatorB2.move(275, 50)
        self.CreatorL = QLabel("Created By: PapaKliffy", self)
        self.CreatorL.move(20, 350)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), QPixmap("background.jpg"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = UICreator()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**background.png:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]